# Working with fields

Tags: sql, vba, autocad

I'm trying to create the SQL Database based on this VBA programming, but have no idea what the table name should be, what the column names should be, or what values go into the rows when this part of the program is querying here in this example below. Could someone help? I do know that InsertForm is using a form to insert values, but I get lost at .LayerType.AddItem and .LayerList.Column

```
InsertForm.LayerList.Clear
RC = 1
InsertForm.LayerType.Clear
InsertForm.LayerList.Clear
InsertForm.LayerType.AddItem "Schematic"
InsertForm.LayerType.AddItem "Panel Layout"
InsertForm.LayerType.AddItem "General Arrangement"
Set RS = DB.GetConnection.Execute("select * from Layers where ProjectNUMBER = 'STANDARD' Order By LAYERName ASC")
InsertForm.LayerList.AddItem "Name"
InsertForm.LayerList.Column(1, 0) = "Color"
InsertForm.LayerList.Column(2, 0) = "LineType"
InsertForm.LayerList.Column(3, 0) = "LineWeight"
While RS.EOF = False
InsertForm.LayerList.AddItem Trim(RS.Fields.Item(2))
InsertForm.LayerList.Column(1, RC) = Trim(RS.Fields.Item(3))
InsertForm.LayerList.Column(2, RC) = Trim(RS.Fields.Item(4))
InsertForm.LayerList.Column(3, RC) = Trim(RS.Fields.Item(5))
RC = RC + 1
RS.MoveNext
Wend
InsertForm.MultiPage1.value = 0
InsertForm.MultiPage2.value = 0
InsertForm.Show 
End Sub
```

Comment: There's no way of knowing what the DB would look like, because it uses a `SELECT *`. All that can be seen is the name of two columns fromt he WHERE clause (ProjectNUMBER and LAYERName). You can speculate that it might have three additional columns (Color, LineType, and LineWeight), but nothing more about the DB. Contact the original author of the code or find a copy of the original database.

Comment: Actually. I did figure it out. The original author collected this code from examples in books and online....and is also unknown. However. First the columns are color, line type, line weight. Last three columns are project number, layer name, and Fields. The records in Fields should be Item (1) , Item (2) and so forth to Item (5).